# web application, best way to handle state

Tags: http, session, cookies, session-state

I have some crud pages for which I have to store some state information, like current page, records per page, current order, filter conditions, and sometimes way more information...

I'd like to use friendly urls similar to rest style, something like http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls (GET for browsing, POST to add, PUT to edit, DELETE to remove)

The problem with cookies is that if I open several tabs, all of them would share the same cookies, it's the same with the session because the session id is stored in a cookie

if I try to keep those params in the url (something like GET /clients?page=1&len=10&sort=name&filter=smith) as soon as I issue a POST I loose those values

the other solution would be to store the state on hidden inputs, and to always issue posts carrying around those hidden inputs, but in that case I can't use GET for queries...

so, how do you handle web presentation state???

--

added:

to be more specific

I have a crud page, the user can filter, change page, page length, and 
sort order..

After issuing an update or insert, how can I retrieve the former page, 
page length, sort order, criteria filters (that presentation logic 
state), etc... taking into account that if the user opens another tab 
both tabs would work with the same cookies...

the only solution I can think of is to use hidden fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do both of your suggestions, I think.

Whenever you generate a page server-side, make sure any of the forms on the page have your params as hidden values, and any links have the params in the URL...

Comment: you mean to have it all both, on input hidden and in the querystring... I was trying to avoid that duplicate effort...

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean...  It's not really any duplicated effort, since either way you need to put those parameters in your generated HTML.  The only difference is that you'll need to put them on the query string in some places, and as form parms in others.  I guess if you're using a web framework that treats params on the query string separately from params that come in as part of a POST or a PUT you might have some extra work?

Comment: you are right, I could develop some function that handle it transparently, saving and loading them them to the url or hidden input accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want cookies and sessions, your only option is to pass them around as query string parameters (on GETs) and hidden fields (on form POSTs).

Answer (score 1):

**on clarification**

What's the problem with storing different key-value pairs for different pages? E.g., for page `/product/4` you can store keys `product-4-order`, `product-4-filter`, etc.

Or am I missing your intention?

**edit**
Another alternative is to not refresh the current page *completely* and do all manipulations with AJAX. Settings won't be persisted between sessions, though.

Comment: the problem is the user might open the same page in two different tabs... they would share the same cookies and session